# Testing javascript privileged methods in jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I want to to write a test for a privileged method in javascript (new to both jasmine and javascript) but unfortunately I am having a hard time understanding how to expose my method correctly.

I know that I cannot test private methods but I think I should be able to test privileged methods - right or wrong?

When I run the code in a browser, calling `song.bottlesOrBottle();` returns the correct adjective. Yet my jasmine code to test if `bottleOrBottles();` is exposed returns undefined.

Apparently, there is concept in either JavaScript or jasmine (maybe both) that I do not yet understand.  Can someone please help me out by explaining why my test fails?  I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

PS: I have also tried extracting the `bottlesOrBottle` into a prototype method but though the code runs correctly in my browser, none of the jasmine test I write pass for the prototype. If necessary I can paste that code here but would like to concentrate on understanding one concept first. Again, thank you for your help.

**CODE**

```
function Song(numberOfBottles){
var self = this;

  var lyrics = [];

  // bottlesOrBottle();

  this.bottlesOrBottle = function (){
     return adjectiveToUse();
  }


  function adjectiveToUse(){
    return (self.numberOfBottles <=1? '' : 's');
  }

  setNumberOfBottles();

  function setNumberOfBottles(){
    var error = 'this constructor accepts numbers between 1 and 10';

    if (numberOfBottles === undefined || numberOfBottles < 1 || numberOfBottles > 10) {
      throw new Error(error);
    } else{
      self.numberOfBottles = numberOfBottles;
    };
  }
}
```

**TEST**

```
describe('Song Constructor', function() {
  var song;
  beforeEach(function(){
    song = new Song(10);
  });

  describe('if not passed an argument', function(){
    it('should throw an error', function(){
      expect(function(){new Song()}).toThrow(new Error('this constructor accepts numbers between 1 and 10'));
    });
  });

  describe('if passed a number less than 1 or greater than 10', function(){
    it('should throw an error', function(){
      expect(function(){new Song()}).toThrow(new Error('this constructor accepts numbers between 1 and 10'));
    });
  });

  describe('if passed a number between 1 - 10', function(){
    it('should store numberOfBottles property on creation of a new song', function(){
      expect(song.numberOfBottles).toEqual(10);
    });
  });

  describe('bottlesOrBottles method', function(){
    it('is exposed', function(){
      debugger;
      expect(song.bottlesOrBottles()).toEqual('s');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: It looks like the test is looking for `bottlesOrBottles`, but the method is `bottlesOrBottle`.

Comment: @AndrewLarson : thank you so much for spotting that type!!!